# I used the Tax-meta-class by bainternet but i still can't get it to display any of the results.

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

here's my code:

```
 $config = array(
    'id' => 'tax_meta_box',          // meta box id, unique per meta box
    'title' => 'Tax Meta Box',          // meta box title
    'pages' => array('category'),        // taxonomy name, accept categories, post_tag and custom taxonomies
    'context' => 'normal',            // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
    'fields' => array(),            // list of meta fields (can be added by field arrays)
    'local_images' => false,          // Use local or hosted images (meta box images for add/remove)
    'use_with_theme' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/Tax-Meta-Class/Tax-meta-class'          
  );
  /*
   * Initiate your meta box
   */
  $my_meta =  new Tax_Meta_Class($config);
  //Image field
  $my_meta->addImage('image_field',array('name'=> __('My Image ','tax-meta')));

  $my_meta->Finish();
```

// And here is the line in my home page

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( 'category' );
            foreach($terms as $p_cat):
                $term_id = $p_cat->term_id;
                $saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'image_field',true);
                echo '<pre>';
                echo $term_id; // Echoes '1' which is the category ID
                echo $saved_data; // Doesn't show anything . Wonder Why!!
                exit;

                ?>
```

Not just Image, i can't get it to display other text fields etc as well.. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight catch to using [bainternet's Tax Meta Class](https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class): the way you save and retrieve data changes depending on your Wordpress version.

> If you are using the latest version of WordPress then use
>   `get_term_meta` instead of `get_tax_meta`.
>
> - https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class/issues/115#issuecomment-170365995

I believe the exact version is WordPress 4.4.

- If your WP version is before 4.4, use `get_tax_meta`.
- If you are 4.4 and above, use `get_term_meta`.